# Type check error while trying to call overloaded function

Tags: typescript

I have an overloaded function:

```
function find(id: number);
function find(id: string);
function find(id: number | string) {
  // do stuff
}
```

But when I try to call it like this, I get an error:

```
function test(id: string | number) {
  return find(id);
}
```

Error - `No overload matches this call`. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final line of the the overload serves to combine the two overload signatures into an implementation. It isn't considered an overload signature of its own so that's why you are getting the error.  As silly as it sounds, if you want to allow `string`, `number`, **and** `number | string` you can just copy the final line and make it an additional overload.

```
function find(id: number);
function find(id: string);
function find(id: number | string);
function find(id: number | string) {
  // do stuff
}
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGYAmAKGaBciwgC2ARgKYBOAlHgG5zYDcAUKJLAsqptngM5TlUAc2qI6jFuGjwkKdFlz4iZcogA%20ifoLAja9NM1bSOc7ooIkK6zQOGVEAbyaJEAeleI0cGyGDAmAL5MkmwyiFCk-AA8ACqIpAAeEei8NtpC1hYqAHwKeDH2Ti7kpFAg5LJcCpTMAUA)